# Bitcoind python connection

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, python

I'm trying to connect to bitcoind with python3. I'm currently following the instructions of Antonopolous book.

This is my code on an IDE:

```python
from bitcoin.rpc import RawProxy
p = RawProxy()
info = p.getinfo()
print(info['blocks'])
```

Unfortunately I only get warnings:

```
/home/pariya/python_pr/venv/bin/python /home/pariya/python_pr/main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pariya/python_pr/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitcoin/rpc.py", line 190, in __init__
    with open(cookie_file, 'r') as fd:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pariya/.bitcoin/.cookie'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pariya/python_pr/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    p = RawProxy()
  File "/home/pariya/python_pr/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitcoin/rpc.py", line 313, in __init__
    super(RawProxy, self).__init__(service_url=service_url,
  File "/home/pariya/python_pr/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitcoin/rpc.py", line 197, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Cookie file unusable (%s) and rpcpassword not specified in the configuration file: %r' % (err, btc_conf_file))
ValueError: Cookie file unusable ([Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pariya/.bitcoin/.cookie') and rpcpassword not specified in the configuration file: '/home/pariya/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm running bitcoind on an external hard drive. Is something missing in my code?

Thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Two important errors in the output you present are:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pariya/.bitcoin/.cookie'
```

and

```
ValueError: Cookie file unusable ([Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pariya/.bitcoin/.cookie') and rpcpassword not specified in the configuration file: '/home/pariya/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf'
```

The later says that you did not provide *RPC password* via configuration file and cookie file is missing too.

You probably missed some init steps in your code (to login to bitcoind RPC server) or you should create a file `/home/pariya/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` and configure RPC password there:

```
rpcuser=johndoe
rpcpassword=enteryourpassword
```

Please note that the values of these parameters must match those configured in bitcoind obviously.

Comment: I don't know why it is searching for the file in my home directory. My bitcoin directory is on the external hard drive. I also have the conf file with a set rpcuser and rpcpassword in it.

Comment: Although `bitcoind` is placed on external drive, your code and the python library acts as a client and it look for the config in the default location.

Also, if the package you use is `bitcoin` (see https://pypi.org/project/bitcoin/), it's not maintained anymore and it could be quite outdated. I would look for some up-to-date package, e.g. `bitcoin-utils` (https://pypi.org/project/bitcoin-utils/) could do the same thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your script seems to not be able to find the cookie file, necessary to authenticate to `bitcoind`. Most likely `bitcoind` is not running on the right network.